# GCC: what's the default value when a symbol is defined on command line?

Tags: c, gcc

The following test code shows that a `-DMY_FLAG` on command line gives the symbol `MY_FLAG` a non-zero value, according to my understanding of [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/If.html):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
#if MY_FLAG
    printf("MY_FLAG\n");
#else
    printf("hello, world!\n");
#endif
}
```

```
$ gcc -DMY_FLAG test.c && ./a.out
MY_FLAG
$ gcc -DMY_FLAG=0 test.c && ./a.out
hello, world!
$ gcc -DMY_FLAG=1 test.c && ./a.out
MY_FLAG
$ gcc test.c && ./a.out
hello, world!
$ gcc -Wundef test.c && ./a.out
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:5:5: warning: "MY_FLAG" is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
    5 | #if MY_FLAG
      |     ^~~~~~~
hello, world!
```

Is this the expected behavior? If yes, then why? What's the value of `MY_FLAG` after `-DMY_FLAG`, i.e. without explicitly assign a value to it such as `-DMY_FLAG=1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default value for a macro defined on the command line is `1`: `-DMY_FLAG` is equivalent to `-DMY_FLAG=1`.

You can check this with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define xstr(x) #x
#define str(x) xstr(x)

int main(void) {
#ifdef MY_FLAG
    printf("MY_FLAG=%s\n", str(MY_FLAG));
#else
    printf("MY_FLAG is not defined\n");
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

The C Standard does not mandate this behavior but it would take a perverse compiler to not mimic the original `pcc` as all others have for 40 years including [**gcc**](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options) and [**clang**](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#preprocessor-flags).

Answer (score 0):

The [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options) says the behavior of `-D name` is to:

> Predefine *name* as a macro, with definition 1.